# tomcat 5 having error log4j

Tags: tomcat, log4j

Whenever i start my tomcat 5, the following error occur,

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

how this can be solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this happens when the log4j system is not configured properly. I get this error usually when an application running under Tomcat is missing the log4j.xml or log4j.properties, or alternatively missing a required JAR.

If you are deploying an application make sure that there is at least a log4j.properties file the web applications WEB-INF/classes folder (or log4j.xml) if you are using XML config. Make sure that the log4j.jar file and perhaps commons-logging.jar file are in WEB-INF/lib directory.

If it's not application specific there is a good reference at:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

For configuring the logging for the Tomcat itself.